# org.json.JSONArray cannot convert list of maps correctly in Android 4.2.1

Tags: android, json

Android 4.2.1.

```
List<Map<String, String>> printers = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> printerInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
printerInfo.put("name", "prn1");
printerInfo.put("address", "addr1");
printers.add(printerInfo);

printerInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
printerInfo.put("name", "prn2");
printerInfo.put("address", "addr2");
printers.add(printerInfo2);

org.json.JSONArray arrBTPrinters = new org.json.JSONArray(printers);
System.out.println(arrBTPrinters.toString());
```

This code prints

```
[
   "{address=addr1, name=prn1}",
   "{address=addr2, name=prn2}"
]
```

But correct JSON array should look like

```
[
   {"address":"addr1", "name":"prn1"},
   {"address":"addr2", "name":"prn2"}
]
```

Is it a bug in Android 4.2.1 or I should use different Java structure?

Comment: do you want the json object To be quoted? it doesnt look correct although its valid

Comment: Did you ever find out if this was a bug in org.json on 4.2.1 or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//build objects
JSONObject printer1 = new JSONObject(printerInfo);
JSONObject printer2 = new JSONObject(printerInfo2);

//build array
org.json.JSONArray arrBTPrinters = new org.json.JSONArray();
arrBTPrinters.put(printer1);
arrBTPrinters.put(printer2);

//print
System.out.println(arrBTPrinters.toString());
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but rather works around the issue. Is this a known limitation of org.json on 4.2.1?